# Return a flatten list from my recursive function in Python

Tags: python, list, recursion, flatten

```
def flatten(aList):
    if len(aList) == 1:
        return aList
    else:
        return flatten(aList[:-1])]
```

I want it to return a flatten list of the original list, pass to the function. After passing it this a list, it only returns the first element.

```
List = [68, -99,"abc", -8,100, [-92, 89, 81, 96]]
flatten(List)
```

Comment: Sure.  Search StackOverflow for questions about flattening a list in Python.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2158532/5827958) answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
List = [68, -99,"abc", -8,100, [-92, 89, 81, 96]]

result = []
def flatten(my_list):
    for i in my_list:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            return flatten(i)
        else:
            result.append(i)
    return result

print(flatten(List))
```

Comment: That was better! thank you